# How to find the lowest price item(s) in a list

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a query to find the cheapest item(s) in a table. So lets say I have a table with:

```
ID   Price
123   4    
234   5   
456   6    
567   4
```

So I would want a result that prints out:

```
123    
567
```

I have written

```
select id, min(price)
from list
```

but this prints out both the price and id. And I only want the id.

I also tried

```
select id, min(price)
from list
group by id
```

to try and get multiply items if some items have the same lowest price. But this ended up printing out the entire table. I'm stumped on what to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use this:

```
SELECT id
FROM list
WHERE price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM list);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of using a where but wasn't sure how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query.

```
SELECT
  id
FROM list
WHERE price IN (SELECT
  MIN(price)
FROM list)
```